# InternetQueryOption with INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY returns empty strings instead of the set proxy settings

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, wininet

Used `InternetOpen` with a set proxy server (`127.0.0.1:5401`) and bypass (`<-loopback>`) but, when doing `InternetQueryOption` with the option set to `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY`, the returned strings, in the `INTERNET_PROXY_INFO` struct, are empty, but the access type is correct, `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY`.

here is the sig for `InternetQueryOption` and the `INTERNET_PROXY_INFO` struct, maybe I am doing something wrong:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool InternetQueryOption([In] IntPtr hInternet, [In] INTERNET_OPTION option, [In, Out] IntPtr buffer, [In, Out] ref int bufferSize);

public enum INTERNET_OPTION : uint
{
    PROXY = 38
}

public enum INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE : uint
{
    PRECONFIG,
    DIRECT,
    PROXY = 3,
    PRECONFIG_WITH_NO_AUTOPROXY
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
{
    public INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE accessType;
    private fixed char proxy[500];
    private fixed char proxyBypass[500];
}
```

Note that I have tried every possible variant of the struct:

1) `proxy` and `proxyBypass` being `string` with `MarshalAs(ByValTStr, 500)`;

2) `proxy` and `proxyBypass` being `string` and assigning to them a string which is 500 of the 0 characters;

3) The above 2 variants but with the struct being a class.

All 3 return the correct `accessType` of `PROXY` but the other 2 fields are empty strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INTERNET_PROXY_INFO needs to be a big blob of memory, WinINet will set the string pointers for you.

```
public class WinApi
{

public enum INTERNET_OPTION : uint { PROXY = 38 }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct INTERNET_PROXY_INFOA
{
    public IntPtr accessType;
    public string proxy;
    public string proxyBypass;
}

[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int InternetQueryOptionA([In] IntPtr hInternet, [In] INTERNET_OPTION option, [In, Out] IntPtr buffer, [In, Out] ref int bufferSize);

}
```

You could allocate a blob of memory and hope it is large enough or ask the function:

```
int cb = 0;
WinApi.InternetQueryOptionA(IntPtr.Zero, WinApi.INTERNET_OPTION.PROXY, IntPtr.Zero, ref cb);
IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(cb);
int succ = WinApi.InternetQueryOptionA(IntPtr.Zero, WinApi.INTERNET_OPTION.PROXY, data, ref cb);
if (succ != 0)
{
    WinApi.INTERNET_PROXY_INFOA info = (WinApi.INTERNET_PROXY_INFOA) Marshal.PtrToStructure(data, typeof(WinApi.INTERNET_PROXY_INFOA));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{2}: {0}|{1}", info.proxy, info.proxyBypass, info.accessType));
}
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
```

Comment: nvm, seams it does work but only for the ANSI version of `InternetQueryOption`. If it's the unicode version then the returned is something like `瑨灴ㄽ㜲〮〮\u312e㠺㠸‸瑨灴㵳㈱⸷⸰⸰㨱㠸㠸栀`, which is odd considering that it's possible to retrieve the user agent name via the unicode version.

Comment: Parts of WinInet actually works better as Ansi. I can try Unicode tomorrow but even then, this is not the preferred way to get the proxy. IEv5 added a different per-connection option that Microsoft recommends that you use.

Comment: INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY does not support Unicode AFAIK. Use INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION for Unicode but it is probably just going to call the Ansi function and convert the result.

Comment: Late reply but, i found a way to use it in `InternetQueryOptionW`. Sins strings, when used in unicode versions of functions, are marshaled by default as LPWStr the way to make `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY` work is to apply to both the `proxy` and `proxyBypass` fields the attribute `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`

Comment: `InternetQueryOptionW` just calls `InternetQueryOptionA` on options it does not understand and it does NOT understand `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY` on the Windows versions I tested. `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)` is the same as `CharSet.Ansi` I did for the struct.